# How to count the sale of each day according stocks with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count the sale of each day. The values in the original table are stocks but not sale.
I use excel to solve the problem,But now I have millions of products ,so I want to solve the problem with pandas.

[image: The original table like this:]

[image: I want to generate the table:]

I am still new to programming and Pandas but I have read up on pandas docs and am still unable to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pandas.DataFrame.diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) is enough.

```py
df['STOCK'] = df['STOCK'].diff()
df.rename(columns={'STOCK': 'SALE'}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'ID1_stock': 'ID1_sale', 'ID2_stock': 'ID2_sale', 'ID3_stock': 'ID3_sale'}, level=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) with `rename` first first level of `MultiIndex` and then second by lambda function:

```
print (df) 
      STOCK          
  ID1_stock ID2_stock
0        20        21
1        18        20
2        16        19

df = (df.diff()
        .rename(columns={'STOCK': 'SALE'}, level=0)
        .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('stock','sale'), level=1))
print (df)
      SALE         
  ID1_sale ID2_sale
0      NaN      NaN
1     -2.0     -1.0
2     -2.0     -1.0
```